# Why can't we add URL behind the amp image? After adding the image doesn't get render in Gmail

Tags: amp-html, amp-email, amp-form

I need to add URLs behind every images (amp-img tag) in AMP for email. I see that when I add below code to implement this, the image rendering goes off in Gmail. Is there a work around to achieve this? If I remove tag  from below it works perfectly.

```html
<a href="https://www.samsung.com/uk/tv-accessories/customisable-frame-vg-scft50-vg-scft50be-xc/" target="_blank">
        <amp-img id="c3" width="0" height="0" [width]="updateC3.width" [height]="updateC3.height"  src=
"https://res.m1.email.samsung.com/res/samsung_mid_prod1/779fbea9a74e02d9afd4340c829b5334.JPG"
                class="gfg">
            </amp-img></a>
            <a href="https://www.samsung.com/uk/tv-accessories/customisable-frame-vg-scft50-vg-scft50wt-xc/" target="_blank">
            <amp-img id="c4" width="0" height="0" [width]="updateC4.width" [height]="updateC4.height"  src=
"https://res.m1.email.samsung.com/res/samsung_mid_prod1/2cf8b6496a81bddade877985c6fad11b.JPG"
                class="gfg">
            </amp-img></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial `width` and `height` of the two images are `0`, which means that the images will initially be invisible. You do have `[width]` and `[height]` attributes that binds the width and height to a dynamic value using `amp-bind`, but `amp-bind` doesn't evaluate bindings until the first user gesture or in special occasions such as evaluating the binding in an `amp-list` template when the `amp-list` refreshes.

If the images are not in a template of `amp-list`, then the image's width and height will stay at 0 until the first user gesture. In that case you do need to give them a non-zero width and height for the images to be visible.

Comment: thanks for replying. These 2 images are just part of the image lists. There are 4 images as of now and by default first image will have width and height of 300 each. So I see that first image getting displayed when I remove <a> tag. But when I wrap each of the amp-img tags with <a> then images goes off.

Comment: Please include the entire AMP HTML that reproduces the described issue.